# Figure 1.4 of Introduction to Calculus and analysis vol 1

Tags: reference-request

[image]

I get stuck in here.
Should it be 10 11 100 101 *110*?
Should "21/4" lie between 101 and 110 instead of 111?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're right.  The integer at the right of 101 should be *110*.

The reason is that $110_2 = 5<\dfrac{21}{4}<6 = 110_2<7=111_2$.

There's nothing wrong in the equation that you underlined.

$$c_0 = d_0 + p d_1 + p^2 d_2 + \cdots + p^k d_k,$$

where $d_0,d_1,\dots,d_k \in \{0,1,\dots,p-1\}$ because the formula represents $c_0$ in base $p$.

In the picture, there're some digits $0$'s and $1$'s because the figure shows the representation of $\dfrac{21}4$ in the *binary* system.

Comment: It is nothing wrong with that I underlined.Should "21/4" lie between 101 and110 instead of 111?

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the title of your question.

Comment: It doesn't matter

Comment: um...I want to accept your answer...but this book is "kind of" famous one,I'm not sure about that........

Comment: Even famous book can have tiny printing errors.  You may search "errata" for any published book on Google.

Comment: ......google gave me nothing ......whatever,thank your very much!